# Java como funciona null

Tags: java

Hola buenas estoy aprendiendo java y tengo dudas con lo siguiente.

```
public class NodoInt{
    NodoInt siguiente;
    int elemento;
}
```

Mi pregunta viene mas del lado con la palabra reservada null, si hago lo siguiente en un main.

```
    NodoInt n = new NodoInt();
    NodoInt x = null;
```

Porque son distintos? tengo entendido que null significa vacío o que en un objeto creado hay variables sin inicializar. si pudieran explicarme se los agradecería.

Comment: null significa "vacío" en plan, no hay nada ahí. new NodoInt() te devuelve un objeto de tipo NodoInt. Un objeto instanciado jamás será null porque bueno... es un objeto instanciado, no un null! No puede ser lo mismo no tener nada, que tener algo. Por cierto, *o que en un objeto creado hay variables sin inicializar* -> Mentira, un objeto creado es un objeto creado. Este objeto ***DENTRO DE EL*** podrá tener algún null, pero el objeto en si, nunca va a ser null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La palabra reservada **`null`** indica que una variable que referencia a un objeto se encuentra "sin objeto", es decir, la variable ha sido declarada pero no apunta a ningún objeto.

**`null`** no es un objeto ni un tipo. Es solo un valor especial, que se puede asignar a cualquier tipo de referencia y se puede castear **`null`** a cualquier tipo, ejemplo `String a = (String)null;` pero al final sigue siendo un `null`.

Ya sea que declares tu variable `NodoInt x = null;` o `NodoInt x;` ambos hacen referencia de que no apuntan a ningún objeto.

En tu ejemplo:

```
NodoInt n = new NodoInt();
NodoInt x = null;
```

Ambos son del mismo tipo, pero la diferencia es que `n` apunta a un nuevo `NodoInt()` que puedes utilizar a diferencia de `x` que *"la declaraste"* pero no apunta a ningún objeto "No lo puedes utilizar" es como una variable flotando sin rumbo "no tiene valor como tal" es decir que no vale nada.